# Several servers on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a question, how to run several servers on Heroku?
For example: I have GraphQL API server and Client server. I tried to set two 'web' in Procfile but it didn't help.

What is proper way to handle several servers that should be accessible from the internet. One thing is that the "Client server" should somehow get the port for "API" server because of Server Side Rendering.

The ideal variant I would like to have is something like that: I set two 'web' (i.e. the first one is default) in Procfile and inside the scripts I can get 'process.env['web.1'].PORT' and 'process.env['web.2'].PORT' in every script. In this case I know the ports of servers so they could send requests each other and I can have access from public Internet.

Thanks.

Comment: You'd need to run multiple apps.

Comment: So how to organize microservice architecture in this case?

Comment: Each microservice as a separate Heroku app.

Comment: And even if I create several process in one dyne i can't get port of other process and get access to it?

Comment: You only get one port exposed to the web. Again, you need multiple apps if you want to run multiple web-accessible services.

Comment: Yes, one port is exposed to the internet, but i thought that internally several processes in one dyno can talk each other.
About several apps, there is a problem if you have monorepo, because for both apps there will be one repo and one Procfile

Comment: You could use an environment variable to tell each app which service from the monorepo to run.